# fcm plugin show push notification inside the application via alert using ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-notifications

all I am using ionic to build an application and working with push notification functionality using FCM plugin in firebase.

It's working fine but when I click the notification, I need to open my app and show one alert and display the notification message inside the app I tried as below but I am not able to get properly.

I attached my code, please help how to solve this problem I didn't get any error in console also

## code

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
  
})
app.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      debugger;
      FCMPlugin.getToken(
        function (token)
         {
          debugger;
          alert('Token: ' + token);
          console.log('Token: ' + token);
        },
        function (err) {
          debugger;
          alert('error retrieving token: ' + token);
          console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
        }
      );

      FCMPlugin.onNotification(
        function (data)
         {
          debugger;
          if (data.wasTapped) {
            //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
            alert("Tapped: " + JSON.stringify(data));
          } else {
            //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
            alert("Not tapped: " + JSON.stringify(data));
          }
        },
        function (msg) {
          debugger;
          alert('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
          console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
        },
        function (err) {
          debugger;
          alert('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
          console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
        }
      );

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

})
```

Comment: can u try in $ionicpopup inside if (data.wasTapped) {} block?

Comment: same not working @Utpaul